# Mapping a Object map property to Map using Dozer

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

How Can I map a map object property values to map using dozer.

Here is my class :

```
public class SimplePojo {
private String field1;
private String field2;
private Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();

public String getField1() {
    return field1;
}

public void setField1(String field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}

public String getField2() {
    return field1;
}

public void setField2(String field2) {
    this.field2 = field2;
}

public Map<String, String> getAttributes() {
    return attributes;
}

public void setAttributes(Map<String, String> attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes;
}
```

}

attributes map is having some Key-Value pairs like `<key1-value1>` etc.
This data should go with object properties as key-value pair to the resulting map.

How can I do this mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I haven't tried this but the dozer documentation has the details, have you tried this?

http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mapbackedproperty.html

Comment: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mapbackedproperty.html This gives you map to map mapping right? I have a situation where my first map is property of a class and Iwant that in a resulting map.